# oracle exception empty message

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am using Oracle Client 11.2.0.4.22 to build my C# ASP.Net application.
Everything is okay when I run it locally, but it throw OracleException with empty exception message when I run in a test web server.

I found out that one of the reason that cause empty exception message is the dataaccess.dll unble to load the dependency library properly.

Here is what I did but still no success:

1. Make sure oracle Version on local and test web server are the same.
2. Specify the targeted platform to x86 on project properties and using the x86 dataaccess.dll.
3. Try to get the full trace of Oracle by specify the TraceFileName in web-config, but seem like the IIS server don't have write permission.

As below is the exception:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "",
  "ExceptionType": "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException",
  "StackTrace": "   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
                    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
                    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n   at E3.WebServices.Repositry.OracleE3FDRepository.CheckConnection() in C:\\Users\\lokingwei\\Source\\Repos\\SRV-E3Server - 4.5.2\\E3.WebServices\\E3.WebServices\\Repositry\\OracleE3FDRepository.cs:line 34
                    at E3.WebServices.Controllers.OCAPHistController.GetConnectionCheck(String Env, String Site) in C:\\Users\\lokingwei\\Source\\Repos\\SRV-E3Server - 4.5.2\\E3.WebServices\\E3.WebServices\\Controllers\\OCAPHistController.cs:line 46
                    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
                    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
                    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Here's my question:

1. Is there any other reason the throw empty exception?
2. On the Stack Trace, it actually specific the path on my local PC, is it possible is the IIS path problem? Since it cannot write the trace file as well.

Comment: *"Make sure oracle Version on local and test web server are the same."* - make sure that oracle.dataaccess.dll registered in server GAC is the same... x86? - this is depends on your pool and compilation and also, Ora Client in this case must be x86 too. *"IIS server don't have write permission."* - so, configure your app pool identity properly

Comment: The Oracle version are same, dll inside GAC are same, the .Net application is already set to build in x86... I try to work on IIS now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is because the IIS user account do not have read permission toward the C:/Oracle directory.

Solved by providing the read permission to IIS user account.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this before and it seems there's a problem loading `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. What worked for us is that we removed `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from the project references and copied the dll to the project folder then re-added the reference to the dll using the copied one.

After adding back the reference, set the following:

```
Copy Local: True
Embed Interop Services: False
Specific Version: False
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where DLL resides during compilation. If Ora client installed on server properly, the dll will be registered in GAC

Comment: Agree... I try everything to change the Oracle.dataaccess.dll location... Is it good to move on to Oracle Xcopy?